# How can we integrate Cash App payment method in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, payment, square

I want to add cashApp payment method to my flutter application and I did some work on it but failed to find the exact method of integration in flutter.
Is `square_in_app_payments` dependency is used for cashApp?
Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: which type of payment method you have to need

Comment: I want to integrate cash app for direct payments.

Answer (score 0):

At this time Cash app payments aren't currently available with our In-App Payments SDK which includes the Flutter plugin. We’re constantly working to improve our features based on feedback like this, so I’ll be sure to share your request to the API product team.

Comment: ok, but how can I integrate it using the method channel? I mean I am unable to find its android and ios code as well.

Comment: That's right, there isn't any Android or iOS code for Cash app payments since it's not currently available. At this time its only available in web.

Comment: can we do it using the web api from the mobile app?